# Link directly to document and have it work after login has completed

Tags: xpages

I have an page home.xsp that logs a user into my application.  After the authentication is successful it goes to HomeAfterLogin.xsp which is the home/landing page of the application.

Yesterday I got to the point of creating emails that are triggered by status events in the app.  In the emails I can include a direct link to the document in question.  The direct link works if you are already authenticated, if not it takes you the login page (as it should).  After you login, it takes you to the HomeAfterLogin instead of the document you linked to.  When I built that part I did not anticipate that I would link directly to documents.  My login process is largely based on a project from Ferry Kranenburg.

My question is where would I obtain the calling URL from the email or if a user happened to bookmark a document.  I have tried context.getUrl() but it just returns the URL of the login page.  I should be able to compute the property of where to redirect if I knew how to obtain the calling URL.

---

UPDATE:  facesContext.getExternalContext().... also seems to just return the current URL, not the calling URL.

---

SECOND UPDATE: I know what the answer is.  The URL is not accessible anymore because it has already been redirected.  The XPage that is linked to directly contains code in the beforePageLoad event to redirect to the login page if the user is anonymous.  At that point, I can get to the refering URL and store it in a sessionScope variable, and then redirect the page after login if the variable is present. I will answer my own question if this works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the URL is not accessible is that the page has already been redirected.  The XPage that is linked to directly contains code in the beforePageLoad event to redirect to the login page if the user is anonymous.

```
if(session.getEffectiveUserName() == "Anonymous"){
//if the PO document was accessed directly like from a Email link or bookmark
//then the doc id is set to a sessionScope variable and after the login page
//the page is directed to the specific PO instead of the HomeAfterLogin page
sessionScope.URL_document = context.getUrlParameter("doc");
context.redirectToPage("Home.xsp")
}
```

I fixed this setting the docID from the URL to a sessionScope variable prior to redirecting to the login XPage in the same beforePageLoad event.

In the custom property that determines where to redirect after login, I added an if statement that will redirect to the specific document if the sessionScope variable is present.  Otherwise go to the HomeAfterLogin as normal.

```
if(sessionScope.URL_document == ""){
facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + "/HomeAfterLogin.xsp"
} else {
    facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + "/New_PO.xsp?doc=" + sessionScope.URL_document;
}
```

This has fixed the issue for me.